# Excel IF statement involving dates

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I need help creating an if statement that does this---->>>>> if date(e.g 25/09/2020) lookup between date range start date is 25/09/2020 and end date is 24/10/2020 and return day 1 and subsequently for further days with the range and if outside range "error".

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
=IF( AND( TODAY()> DATE(2020, 9, 25), TODAY() < DATE(2020, 10, 24)), 1, "#error") -- returns 1
=IF( AND( TODAY()-30> DATE(2020, 9, 25), TODAY()-30 < DATE(2020, 10, 24)), 1, "#error") -- return #error
```